# How to use cbind on matrices in one list and place them in another (r)

Tags: r, list, matrix, cbind

I'm trying to join matrices stored in nested lists and place them in a new list. For example, if I have a list of fruit, I would like to take various matrices stored under `Kiwi`, and join them together as one matrix in a new list.

This will generate something that looks like my data:

```
#Define some important things
Fruits = c('Mango', 'Kiwi')
Attr = c('Size', 'Shape')

#generate empty lists
MyFruitList <- lapply(Fruits, function(q) {
  EmptySublist <- (setNames(vector("list", length(Fruits)), Attr))
})
names(MyFruitList) <- Fruits

#Full lists with example matrices
MyFruitList[['Mango']][['Size']] <- matrix(c(3,5,7,2), nrow=2, ncol=2)
MyFruitList[['Mango']][['Shape']] <- matrix(c(3,6,7,5), nrow=2, ncol=2)

MyFruitList[['Kiwi']][['Size']] <- matrix(c(1,3,4,2), nrow=2, ncol=2)
MyFruitList[['Kiwi']][['Shape']] <- matrix(c(2,4,5,1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

And here is what I have been trying to use to move the matrices stored under Kiwi and Mango into a new list.

```
#Obviously this doesn't actually work
MyFruitListAsRows <- lapply(Fruits, function(i) {
  MyFruitListAsRows <- matrix(cbind(paste0(MyFruitList[i]))) 
})
names(MyFruitListAsRows) <- paste0(Fruits, "Row")
```

Ideally I should end up with a list called `MyFruitsAsRows` which contains 2, 4 by 2 matrices named `Kiwi` and `Mango`, containing their respective `Size` and `Shape` data from the original `MyFruitList` list.

e.g. For Mango it would look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
[1,]    3    7   3    7
[2,]    5    2   6    5
```

(Sorry that the numbers are overly similar, that was not well planned and might make it hard at first to recognise where I'd like my numbers to go)

Having been constructed from this:

```
$Size
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    7
[2,]    5    2

$Shape
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    7
[2,]    6    5
```

Edit: I have tried to adapt the advice of Ronak Shah and done the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

MyFruitListAsRows <- map(MyFruitList[i], bind_cols)
```

but running either,

```
MyFruitListAsRows[['KiwiRow']]
MyFruitListAsRows[['MangoRow']]
```

Produces:

```
I get Error in x[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

If I try to get RStudio to show me what's in either of my new lists in a window, RStudio encounters a fatal error and crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use base R to loop over each `MyFruitList` and `cbind` them with `do.call`

```
lapply(MyFruitList, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))

#$Mango
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    7    3    7
#[2,]    5    2    6    5

#$Kiwi
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    4    2    5
#[2,]    3    2    4    1
```

You can also use `cbind.data.frame` here.

---

Using `tidyverse` we can `map` over each list and then `cbind`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(MyFruitList, cbind.data.frame)

#$Mango
#  Size.1 Size.2 Shape.1 Shape.2
#1      3      7       3       7
#2      5      2       6       5

#$Kiwi
#  Size.1 Size.2 Shape.1 Shape.2
#1      1      4       2       5
#2      3      2       4       1
```

Comment: Would there be a way to have this so that the data is preserved in 4*2 configuration? Whereby I have 2 rows of 4 columns, with columns 1 and 2 containing the first data set (e.g. the `Size` matrix) and columns 3 and 4 containing the second data set (e.g. the `Shape` matrix)? I tried to see what `bind_columns` produced but it doesn't seem to be the correct way of telling the tidyerse what I'm trying to do. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've added a better example of how I would like my final data to be laid out. If you have a chance to look I'd be really grateful. I thought that 4*2 referred first to the x-axis, and then to the y-axis but this does not appear to be the case, as your 4 * 2 tibble (`# A tibble: 4 x 2`) is the inverse of what I was trying to achieve. Again I really appreciate your help, particularly as this is not the first time you have assisted me.

Comment: I have found that `bind_cols` works to some degree. However when I try to check my matrix using `MyFruitListAsRows[['KiwiRow']]` and `MyFruitListAsRows[['MangoRow']]` I get `Error in x[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds`. When I try to view it in an RStudio window, I get `R session aborted / R encountered a fatal error / The session was terminated`.  Sorry for leaving the above saga in a comment section.

Comment: @SolebaySharp I have updated the answer accordingly. See if it works for you.