# When trying to join matrices the attempt leads to an out of bounds error. (r)

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am trying to join matrices together. My goal is really as simple as to take multiple matrices from one list, marry them, and put them in a new list. To ensure clarity, let me preface this with a very simple example of what I want to do, using only two matrices which are not nested within lists:

```
$Size
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    7
[2,]    5    2

$Shape
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    7
[2,]    6    5
```

Would end up looking like...

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
[1,]    3    7   3    7
[2,]    5    2   6    5
```

Here is the wider context within which I am trying to do this, including sample data.

```
#Define some important things - for sample data
Fruits = c('Mango', 'Kiwi')
Attr = c('Size', 'Shape')

#generate empty lists - for sample data
MyFruitList <- lapply(Fruits, function(q) {
  EmptySublist <- (setNames(vector("list", length(Fruits)), Attr))
})
names(MyFruitList) <- Fruits

#Fill lists with example matrices - for sample data
MyFruitList[['Mango']][['Size']] <- matrix(c(3,5,7,2), nrow=2, ncol=2)
MyFruitList[['Mango']][['Shape']] <- matrix(c(3,6,7,5), nrow=2, ncol=2)

MyFruitList[['Kiwi']][['Size']] <- matrix(c(1,3,4,2), nrow=2, ncol=2)
MyFruitList[['Kiwi']][['Shape']] <- matrix(c(2,4,5,1), nrow=2, ncol=2)

#Now Lets create those new matrices! - The thing I'm trying to
#achieve with my actual data
MyFruitListAsRows <- lapply(Fruits, function(i) {
  MyFruitListAsRows <- map(MyFruitList[i], bind_cols)
})
names(MyFruitListAsRows) <- paste0(Fruits, "Row")
```

And at first glance, everything seems to have worked. But when I go to inspect a matrix e.g.

```
MyFruitListAsRows[['MangoRow']]
```

I ge this error:

```
 Error in x[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Should I try to get RStudio to show me a window containg this problem-matrix, it straight up crashes.

What on earth am I doing that is setting things as 'out of bounds'?

Comment: I think you are looking for a `Reduce` type op, eg. `Reduce(cbind, unlist(MyFruitList, recursive = FALSE))`

Comment: I can't believe it's that straight forward. If you just add this as an answer I can mark it as correct. Seeing as this will also answer [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783446/how-to-use-cbind-on-matrices-in-one-list-and-place-them-in-another-r) you may want to put there too if you would like the extra reputation I will be able to award you. I appreciate your help immensely @jenesaisquoi